# Book: war between two countries, the main character is a dragon rider and there was some kind of dark magic

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago I remember I read a book series that I really liked.

- The main character was the last of his race (I can’t remember what gender the main character was or the race but I thing it were elves).
- There was a huge war between two countries.
- The main character became a dragon rider, but the dragon he/she got didn't like her, at least at first.
- There was some kind of super dark magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you be more specific about when "a few years ago" was?  You should check out the [suggestions for writing a good question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any ideas there for additional details you can add to your question.

Comment: only similar thing is the point 3 but is it "Eragon" ?

Comment: Points 2 and 4 are covered in "Magician" by Raymond E. Feist. Point 1 could be considered covered if it started "A" main character, which would also cover point 3. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43916.Magician

Answer (score 6):

Could it be [*Nihal from the Land of the Wind*](http://www.liciatroisi.it/books/nihal-eng/)? She is half-elf, can't really use magic so she becomes a dragonrider, her dragon OARF lost his previous rider into battle and doesn't like Nihal at first.

I found a detailed summary but only in Italian on the [Italian Wikipedia page for *Nihal*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihal), should be easy to automatically translate it.

Comment: @Erik If this is indeed the correct answer you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark at the side of the answer next to the voting buttons!